# ANTLR 4 can't parse one rule similar to another

Tags: c#, antlr4

I am writing a Rule Engine based on ANTLR 4 for C# (I am using the [Sam Harwell alternative](https://github.com/tunnelvisionlabs/antlr4cs)) but I can't get my grammar correctly parsing my inputs about two rules very similar.

There are probably several others mistakes, but I am stuck with this one for the moment. Also, I am new to ANTLR (except my old days in school ^^), so do not hesitate to give me some tips/explanations :).

My goal are to interprete binary and numeric assignments such as:

- `Fact := Fact1 OR Fact2`

Behind the scene I want it to match the `bin_assign` rule.

- `Fact := 8 * 4`

Behind the scene I want it to match the `num_assign` rule.

But my parser always matchs `num_assign` and failed matching the operator (because it is expecting a NUM_OP or a EOF).

You will see that those two rules start the same way with the FACT token. But my intuition tells me it is not the cause of the issue (as I say, I'm new to ANTLR, it is just my intuition). I wrote those two rules to avoid `Fact := 1 + true` being a right statment.

Here are my grammars:

1. Common lexer rules:

   ```
   lexer grammar Common;

   /*
    * Lexer Rules
    */
   FACT: [a-zA-Z](([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | '_')*[a-zA-Z0-9])?;
   ASSIGN: ':=';
   LITERAL: '\'' .*? '\'' | '"' .*? '"';

   WS : [ \t\r\n]+ -> skip;
   ```
2. Numeric grammar:

   ```
   grammar NumericGrammar;
   import Common;

   /*
    * Parser Rules
    */
   num_stat: num_stat NUM_OP num_stat          # ArithmeticStat
       | '(' num_stat ')'                      # ArithmeticBrakedStat
       | DIGIT                                 # DigitStat
       | FACT                                  # ArithmeticFactStat
       ;

   num_assign: 
       FACT NUM_ASSIGN num_stat                # ArithmeticAssign
       ;

   /*
    * Lexer Rules
    */
   DIGIT: INT | FLOAT;
   INT: ([1-9][0-9]*)?[0-9]; 
   FLOAT: INT(','|'.')[0-9]+;

   NUM_OP: MULT | DIV | ADD | SUB;
   MULT: '*';
   DIV: '/';
   ADD: '+';
   SUB: '-';

   NUM_ASSIGN: MULT_ASSIGN | DIV_ASSIGN | ADD_ASSIGN | SUB_ASSIGN | ASSIGN;
   MULT_ASSIGN: '*=';
   DIV_ASSIGN: '\\=';
   ADD_ASSIGN: '+=';
   SUB_ASSIGN: '-=';
   ```
3. Binary grammar :

   ```
   grammar BinaryGrammar;
   import NumericGrammar;

   /*
    * Parser Rules
    */
   bin_stat: bin_stat BIN_OP bin_stat          # BinaryStat
       | '(' bin_stat ')'                      # BinaryBrakedStat
       | NOT bin_stat                          # NegateStat
       | num_stat COMPARE_OP num_stat          # CompareStat
       | FACT EQUALITY_OP (LITERAL | DIGIT)    # LiteralComparisonStat
       | num_stat IN SET                       # IntervalComparisonStat
       | BOOL                                  # BoolStat
       | FACT                                  # BinaryFactStat
       ;

   bin_assign: 
       FACT ASSIGN bin_stat                    # BinAssign
       ;

   /*
    * Lexer Rules
    */
   BOOL: TRUE | FALSE;
   TRUE: '1' | 'true' | 'True' | 'YES' | 'Yes' | 'yes';
   FALSE: '0' | 'false' | 'False' | 'NO' | 'No' | 'no';

   BIN_OP: AND | OR | EQUALITY_OP;
   COMPARE_OP: EQUALITY_OP | GT | GTE | LT | LTE;
   AND: 'AND' | 'And' | 'and' | '&' | '&&';
   OR: 'OR' | 'Or' | 'or' | '|' | '||';
   EQUALITY_OP: EQUALITY | UNEQUALITY;
   EQUALITY: '=' | '==';
   UNEQUALITY: '<>' | '!=' | '=/=' | '=\\=';
   GT: '>';
   GTE: '>=';
   LT: '<';
   LTE: '<=';
   NOT: '!' | 'NOT' | 'not';
   IN: 'IN' | 'in';
   SET: ('[' | ']') (INT | FLOAT) ';' (INT | FLOAT) ('[' | ']');
   ```
4. Final grammar:

   ```
   grammar Test;
   import BinaryGrammar;

   /*
    * Parser Rules
    */
   r: (IF bin_stat THEN)? assign EOF;
   assign: bin_assign | num_assign;

   /*
    * Lexer Rules
    */
   IF: 'if' | 'IF' | 'If';
   THEN: 'then' | 'THEN' | 'Then';
   ```

Here a screenshot of the execution if needed:[image: bad matching]

Comment: For start I would fix lower/upper case for non-/terminals because it is misleading (see `NUM_ASSIGN`). Anyway, after a minute I see first ambiguity -- when you have `FACT := FACT` I cannot tell if this is `bin_assign` or `num_assign`. Maybe I miss something (fresh after work ;-)). I don't know ANTLR but does it not report any errors/warnings found in your grammar?

Comment: Nop, ANTLR does not report erros/warning in the grammar. I'm not sure of what you mean about non-/terminals but ANTLR makes a difference between `Rule` and `rule` (with a first upper case character, it is a Lexer Rule, with first lower case character it is a Parser Rule).

Comment: That's weird, first thing I did when writing my parser/lexer was reporting errors (https://sourceforge.net/projects/naivelangtools/). After a while I found another issue with your grammar -- `FACT` is redefined. However hunting all those manually... Terminal is what lexer produces, non-terminal is what parser produces (well, a shortcut). It is helpful to distinguish them by case because when you look at all caps you know it is terminal and t cannot "unfold". In your grammar for example `NUM_ASSIGN` unfolds so when you manually verify grammar it is easy to make a mistake assuming it is fixed.

Comment: What you mean is I can't do recursive lexer rules like: `BOOL: TRUE | FALSE;` ? Indeed, now you are telling me, it looks a little bit stupid (and I have done this several times -_-). I'll try to change that and let you know ! (I found the FACT mistake too, I already fixed but thanks ^^)

Comment: No, no, of course you **can**. However IMHO it makes analysis of the rules harder for you (parser/lexer won't mind). So it is just suggestion for easier (manual) reading the rules -- when I read my grammar, when I see two rules with different tokens all in caps (terminal) I know for sure they are different at that point. In your case you have to check that token if it is really terminal and if not, how it can unfold.

Comment: It looks like it does change things for ANTLR. Changing it fixes my problem. Do you want to post the answer ? Or I will, but the credit is yours.

Comment: Funny, I was not aware it might help solve your problem :-). But I am glad you fixed this issue. Anyway, I posted last comment as regular answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using inconsistent naming of tokens makes analysis of the rules harder for you (parser/lexer won't mind). So it is just suggestion for easier (manual) reading the rules -- when I read my grammar, when I see two rules with different tokens all in caps (terminal) I know for sure they are different at that point. In your case you have to check that token if it is really terminal and if not, how it can unfold.

Comment: It looks like it is a limitation of ANTLR. Removing recursive lexer token fixes the issue !

Answer (score 0):

The `FACT` lexer rule will not match `Fact1`

```
FACT: [a-zA-Z](([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | '_')*[a-zA-Z0-9])?;
```

The kleene star in the middle is nominally a greedy operator.  So, all terminal numbers will be captured, leaving nothing to complete the rule.

Just make it non-greedy:

```
FACT: [a-zA-Z](([a-zA-Z0-9] | '.' | '_')*?[a-zA-Z0-9])?;
```

Comment: I don't have any trouble with my FACT rule. If I try your proposition, it does not match my facts correctly.